# R: How to strech the x axis values?

Tags: r

I have a very basic question. I have created a basic x,y-plot and for my x values which span from -1000 to 0 I would like to stretch last 50 units on x-axis so that from -1000 to -50 values are by default one unit apart but from -50 to 0 they should be 10 units apart. is this possible ??? and how would someone like me do this??

thank you

m

UPDATE:
oh, sorry i thought .... well never mind, thnx for the tip:

example

```
x <- c(-1000:-1)
y <- c(1:1000)
plot(x,y)
```

Now the plot is simple linear but i would like to have last 50 x-ticks 10 units apart?? does this make sense??

Comment: Please read [how to make a great r reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) (I didn't downvote, but help us help you).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to transform `x` and re-label the x-axis:

```
xt <- x
xt[x < -50] <- x[x < -50] - 450
xt[x >= -50] <- 10*x[x >= -50]

plot(xt,y,xaxt="n")
axis(1,at=c(200*(-(5:1))-450,-500,-250,0),
     labels = c(-1000,-800,-600,-400,-200,-50,-25,0))
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

How about just an x axis transformation:

```
x <- c(-1000:-1)
y <- c(1:1000)
plot(x,y, type='l')

stretch <- function(x){
  y <- x
  y[x >= -50] <- 10*x[x >= -50]
  y[x < -50] <- x[x < -50] - 500
  y
}

plot(stretch(x), y, type='l', axes=FALSE, frame.plot=TRUE, xlab="", ylab="")
```

---

Alternatively, you can use `lattice`, for starters:

```
df <- data.frame(x,y)
df$panel <- as.integer(df$x > -50)
library(lattice)
with(df, xyplot(y~x|panel, scales=list(x=list(relation="free"))))
```

but there is a lot of tweaking needed to get rid of the break between charts there.